# server to server copy using custom port and private key with passphrase parameter

Tags: linux, ssh, copy, scp, private-key

While copy some file from server to server using scp command custom port and private key with passphrase parameter gives error

Command is like

> scp -i xxxxxxx.pem   -P xxxxx   /path/source-file.zip
>   root@example.com:/path/to/destination/file.zip

error message

```
ssh: connect to host example.com port xxxxx: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

While connecting example.com using privatekey(with custom port and passphrase) is working fine. But not working while we use scp command.

Comment: The syntax looks ok. Are you sure you're not trying to connect to the wrong port? Can you SSH to the box on the same port? Does netcat work (`nc example.com PORT`)?

Comment: Yes its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is not working for me.

So I have used alternate method like `wget` and `CURL`